# I can't get the commands? each of which includes $~\$~$ instead of $~\epsilon~$ of the pushdown automaton

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

The pushdown automaton is given as the below diagram.

[image]

What I know are as below.

$$  1,0 ~\texttt{->}~  \epsilon_{} ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{As 1 is inputted then 0 will be popped from the stack}  $$

$$  0,1 ~\texttt{->}~  \epsilon_{} ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{As 0 is inputted then 1 will be popped from the stack}  $$

$$  0, \epsilon_{} ~\texttt{->}~0 ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{As 0 is inputted  then 0 will be pushed into the stack(Nonexists in the above list)}  $$

What I don't know are as below.

$$  0,  $ ~\texttt{->}~ 0 $ $$

$$  1,  $ ~\texttt{->}~ 1 $ $$

$$  0,0 ~\texttt{->}~ 00 $$

$$  1,1 ~\texttt{->}~ 11 $$

What are them?

Comment: The format of the pushdown instruction seems to be $A \to \alpha $, meaning topmost $A$ is replaced by $\alpha$. In that way we check that topmost symbol $A$ is actually present, in order to distinguish cases. Then $ \$\to 0\$ $ means replace $\$$ by $0\$$, which is the same as push $0$ provided $\$$ is on top of the stack.

Comment: I edited my post a bit.

Comment: I think I got the conception.

Answer (score 0):

I could make this post of the answer because of comments of [Hendrik Jan](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4287/hendrik-jan).

Thank you.

If we assume the input is given as $~ 111000 ~~~$,

The state is moved to $~ q_{1}  ~$ without before input since $~ \epsilon_{}  ~$ exists.

And after the arrival at $~ q_{1}  ~$,$ is pushed at bottom of the stack.

Nextly the procedures of 111000 begin.

At first "1" , the command $~ 1, \\\$ ~ ~\texttt{->}~ 1~$  is done. Which command means that as 1 is inputted, and as a dollar exists at top of the stack, the dollar is replaced by 1 dollar.

This means that 1 is at the top-notch and the second depth element is a dollar.

Nextly we handle the second "1" of the input.

At this time , the command $~ 1,1 ~\texttt{->}~ 11 ~$ is done .

So if we assume the leftmost is top-notch and the rightmost takes the bottom of the stack,

Then newly the stack is seen as like below.

$$  11\\\$ ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{1 is replaced by 11}  $$

As 3rd operation is done ,

$$  111\\\$ ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{leftmost(top notch) 1 is replaced by 11}  $$

As of now, the remaining sequence is 000.

$$~ 0,1 ~\texttt{->}~ \epsilon_{} ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{This will be done triple times}   ~$$

So the three "1" continues from leftmost in the stack,

So after the 3 operations are done, the stack is

$$  \\\$ $$

After the processings of 111000 are done, then the above right command in the diagram is done and finally, the stack is the same as $~ \epsilon_{}  ~$